# C# Linq join 2 Tables

Tags: c#, linq, join, dataset

I want to join 2 Tables with linq or DataRelation. So I have tried with linq firstly, it works great but when I add another object to 1. Tables and join with 2.Table, it doesn't show this object.

Here is my Code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("Kunde");

table.Columns.Add("KundeID", typeof(Int32));
table.Columns.Add("KundeName", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("Produkt", typeof(String));

table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { table.Columns["KundeID"] };

DataTable comment = new DataTable("Comment"); 

comment.Columns.Add("KundeName", typeof(String));
comment.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(String));

comment.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { comment.Columns["KundeName"] };


DataSet ds = new DataSet("DataSet");

ds.Tables.Add(table);
ds.Tables.Add(comment);

object[] o1 = { 1, "Michael", "Jogurt" };
object[] o2 = { 2, "Raj", "Cola" };
object[] o3 = { 3, "Gary", "Fanta" };
***object[] o4 = { 4, "Miky", "Sprite" };***

object[] c1 = { "Raj", "Ich bin cool" };
object[] c2 = { "Gary", "yahoo" };
object[] c3 = { "Michael", "nichts zu verlieren" };


table.Rows.Add(o1);
table.Rows.Add(o2);
table.Rows.Add(o3);
table.Rows.Add(o4);

comment.Rows.Add(c1);
comment.Rows.Add(c2);
comment.Rows.Add(c3);

var results = from table1 in table.AsEnumerable()
              join table2 in comment.AsEnumerable()
              on table1.Field<string>("KundeName") equals table2.Field<string>("KundeName")
              select new
                  {
                      KundeID = table1.Field<Int32?>("KundeID"),
                      KundeName = table1.Field<String>("KundeName"),
                      Produkt = table1.Field<String>("Produkt"),

                      Comment = table2.Field<String>("Comment")
                  };

foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}    {1}    {2}    {3}", item.KundeID, item.KundeName, item.Produkt, item.Comment));
}


Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need all rows from first table whether or not they can be joined to rows from second table, you need a left join:

```
    var results = from table1 in table.AsEnumerable()
                  join table2 in comment.AsEnumerable()
                  on table1.Field<string>("KundeName") equals table2.Field<string>("KundeName") into joined
                  from table3 in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new
                      {
                          KundeID = table1.Field<Int32?>("KundeID"),
                          KundeName = table1.Field<String>("KundeName"),
                          Produkt = table1.Field<String>("Produkt"),

                          Comment = table3 != null ? table3.Field<String>("Comment") : null
                      };
```

This way you can get client named "Miky" but the `Comment` for him is going to be null.

Comment: left join is correct. Thanks a lot. It works GREAT!!!

When I have 3.Table and want to join with 1. and 2. Tables, will it be the same Principle?

Comment: I'm glad to help, if you find answer most helpful you can mark it as correct... Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: @UniLe It depends on what you wish to achieve, you should post some sample data of your third table along with a desired output. You should first try it yourself and if you have problems making it work, open a new question.

Comment: Great :) Left joins (either in LINQ or SQL) don't reduce/filter the result set, they take everything from the "left" table and if some row can't be matched in the right table, they just show right table's fields as null (without removing the row or affecting the fields from the left table).

Answer (score 0):

Your `o4` object doesn't have an object in `comment` that has a matching `KundeName` value, so it is not included in the results.

Perhaps you did not mean to use an inner join?